# how to get aggregate results for jmeter in csv file from command prompt

Tags: excel, csv, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am running a JMETER test plan through command prompt. I want results in excel sheet so saving output file as .csv. But I need the aggregate output in the excel file. I am getting result for all the requests in it. How can I get the only the aggregate result? I know how to do it through GUI. Not able to do it through command prompt. Please can some one guide me how to get the aggregate results.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the Aggregate Report listener and make it write the results in csv format. So that whenever you run the test it in non-gui mode, It writes the result in CSV format.

You can also take a look at [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) to generate reports /  graphs in command line. It can give you the aggregate report in CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

If you download [Standard Plugins Set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/file/JMeterPlugins-Standard-1.4.0.zip) from [Jmeter-plugins.org](http://jmeter-plugins.org) site, then you can use [Synthesis Report](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) instead of Aggregate Report. It has similar functionality but also provide you an ability to filter out the data. So, if you need only the aggregate result, it's possible to display only TOTAL line.